# When did Bitcoin start to allow more than 2 transaction outputs?

Tags: transactions

The original [Bitcoin paper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) specifies that:

> 9. Combining and Splitting Value
>
> (...) Normally there will be either a single input from a larger
> previous transaction or multiple inputs combining smaller amounts,
> **and at most two outputs: one for the payment, and one returning the change, if any, back to the sender**.

As I understand, there is currently no limit on the number of transaction outputs. Was Bitcoin ever implemented in a way that allowed no more than 2 outputs? If so, when did it change, and were there any opposing arguments in the community/from Satoshi for keeping the maximum number of outputs at 2?